# automatic usb backup using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is my automatic usb backup

```
ECHO OFF
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO Back Up USB? Y/N
ECHO. 
Set /P M=Select and press enter.
IF %M%==Y GOTO yes
IF %M%==N GOTO EOF
:yes
set /p drive= What drive?
mkdir D:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\STUFF\BACKUP
XCOPY "%drive%" "D:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\STUFF\BACKUP" /Y /E
```

when it gets to the mkdir line it just quits what could be the problem?

Comment: Try running the `mkdir` command in a cmd prompt, which will tell you if there are any errors.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this file is intended to reside on your PC somewhere and allow you to select the drive to backup. I have a post on my blog which details how you can create a backup bacth file you can keep on the root of each drive you own and have them backup to their own folder on c: drive. You can have a look here: http://www.scotthelme.co.uk/blog/backing-up-your-usb-drives/

Answer (score 0):

REM out your `ECHO OFF`, and see what's going on.  You can actually edit your question and post a copy of what it shows. (Right-Click on the little `C:\` icon in the upper left corner, Select Edit -> Mark. Use your mouse to select the text to copy, then press [ENTER]. The text is now in your clipboard, and you can paste it into your question.

Do you have any spaces in your username? Put double-quotes around `d:\users\%username\desktop\stuff\backup`

What are you entering for `drive`? Just a drive letter? If so, `set drive=%drive%:\`

BTW, unless you've actually created the lable `:eof`, you need a colon when you `GOTO :EOF`.